# Access data of variable in PL/PgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a PL/PgSQL function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_value(firstval integer) RETURNS SETOF mytable AS
$func$
DECLARE
    current mytable;
BEGIN
    SELECT fv FROM mytable WHERE fv = fistval INTO current;
    IF current IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable(fv) VALUES (firstval);
    END IF;
    RETURN current.fv;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need to return a specific row (`fv`) of the `current` variable, but this code is not working (it does not return anything), so how I have to do this?

Comment: It looks like you are declaring variable "mytable" within the function and then selecting from it before it has any value.  So its always NULL.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues:

1. `current` is declared like record. But you try to assign integer value to this composite variable `SELECT INTO`.
2. The return from table functions should be realised by `RETURN TABLE` statement. There are not any table with name `mytable`. In Postgres concept - `RETURNS SETOF mytable` means - returns rows of type like table "mytable".
3. The test `IS NULL` is not safe in this case. You want to check `FOUND` variable.
4. Maybe you don't want to return table - then there is badly used `SETOF` clause.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value(firstval int)
   RETURNS mytable AS $$
   DECLARE
     _r mytable;
   BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE fv = firstval INTO _r;
     IF NOT FOUND THEN
       INSERT INTO mytable(fv) VALUES(firstval);
       SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE fv = firstval INTO _r;
     END IF;
     RETURN _r;
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```

Attention! - this code maybe does what you want, but it is not safe against race conditions. Better to use Postgres statement `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO`.

Please, t[ry to read documentation first](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) - it is designed differently than you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, reading the documentation better I realized that my code was a mess, but I still didn't find the answer to my question: I would like to be able to access the value of a `_r` column without having to make a new query, mainly for some checks present in the original code and that I didn't write here.

Comment: I only noticed now that I had written SELECT fv instead of SELECT *, so I assume that's why I couldn't access a specific column and didn't get anything instead of getting an error - I hadn't selected it. Thanks again

Comment: @CrisMystik if you use `SELECT * INTO _r`, then the value of column `fv` will be available with `_r.fv`. I have not a idea what your function should to return - if you want exactly one value or if you want record (composite value).

Comment: Now I want to return the record - I have to use `SETOF` considerimg that fv is `UNIQUE`?

Comment: @CrisMystik - no - `SETOF` is used when you want to return 0..N rows. When you want exactly one row, then you cannot to use this clause. My example returns composite value.